# What can I do not to calculate buffers in every render(), for DirectX 11?

Tags: c++, directx, buffer, render

I am writing my own 'Engine' class to make it simpler to use DirectX 11 and to learn it. That 'Engine' has a list of objects to render. Some of them are 'Primitives' (own Box class).

The problem is that Box::render() creates a buffers every function call.

**Can I change something with it not to calculate them every function call?**

Maybe I should calculate the g_pIndexBuffer just once in constructor and keep it for each Box? But what with the g_pVertexBuffer and g_pConstantBuffer?

I'm not only asking for the box, but more general - the situation will change when I will want to draw other Primitives or meshes? (for Box I think I could calculate g_pVertexBuffer once, and than just scale object with matrixs).

The code looks now like this (I have skip some parts of code here, the code is based on tutorial from DirectX SDK):

```
Box::render(
    XMFLOAT4X4 &viewM, 
    XMFLOAT4X4 &projectionM, 
    ID3D11Buffer* g_pConstantBuffer, ID3D11DeviceContext* g_pImmediateContext,
    ID3D11VertexShader* g_pVertexShader,
    ID3D11PixelShader* g_pPixelShader,
    ID3D11Device * g_pd3dDevice,
    ID3D11Buffer* g_pIndexBuffer){

    ...
    // Create vertex buffer
    SimpleVertex vertices[] =
{
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
};

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( SimpleVertex ) * 8;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
    InitData.pSysMem = vertices;
ID3D11Buffer* g_pVertexBuffer;
HRESULT hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );

    // Set vertex buffer
UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
    UINT offset = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    WORD indices[] =
    {
    3,1,0, 2,1,3,
    0,5,4, 1,5,0,
    3,4,7, 0,4,3,
    1,6,5, 2,6,1,
    2,7,6, 3,7,2,
    6,4,5, 7,4,6,
    };


    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( WORD ) * 36; // 36 vertices needed for 12 triangles in a triangle list
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    InitData.pSysMem = indices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pIndexBuffer );


    // Set index buffer
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer( g_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0 );

    // Set primitive topology
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

// Create the constant buffer
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer2);
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, NULL, &g_pConstantBuffer );

    ...
    XMMATRIX mSpin = XMMatrixRotationZ( a );
    XMMATRIX mOrbit = XMMatrixRotationY( b );
    XMMATRIX mTranslate = XMMatrixTranslation( c, d, e );
    XMMATRIX mScale = XMMatrixScaling( f, g, h );

    XMMATRIX g_World = mScale * mSpin * mTranslate * mOrbit;

    ConstantBuffer2 cb1;
    cb1.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose( g_World );

    XMMATRIX g_View = XMLoadFloat4x4(&viewM);
    XMMATRIX g_Projection = XMLoadFloat4x4(&projectionM);
    cb1.mView = XMMatrixTranspose( g_View );
    cb1.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose( g_Projection );
    g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource( g_pConstantBuffer, 0, NULL, &cb1, 0, 0 );

    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader( g_pVertexShader, NULL, 0 );
    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer );
    g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader( g_pPixelShader, NULL, 0 );
    g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed( 36, 0, 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the type of buffer. And, of course, on the type of application you are creating.

Vertex and index buffers should be created only once and reused as often as possible. A good place for the creation is the constructor of the class that represents your objects. Furthermore, if there is shared geometry between the objects, you could consider creating a geometry class (something like the `Mesh` in versions up to DX 9). Then you create the buffers once in the constructor of the geometry class and reference the appropriate geometry instances from your objects.

Of course, there are situations, where especially vertex buffers can change throughout the application. But even then, you should create them once at the beginning and then rewrite them when it is necessary. But that should occur as little as possible. Many changed to vertex buffers can be made in an appropriate shader.

For constant buffers, this is a bit trickier. Constant buffers should be divided into data that change:

- never
- per frame
- per frame and per object.
- and maybe others where necessary

And that implies the positions, where they should be created. Never changing buffers should be created once at the beginning of the application (just like vertex and index buffers). Per frame buffers should be created at the beginning of a new frame and per object buffers should be created when rendering the object.

Remember that buffers can exist without being set as the current buffer. Here's how the buffer life cycle would look like:

- create vertex, index and never changing constant buffers
- for each frame

  - create per frame constant buffer
  - for each object

    - create per object constant buffer
    - set vertex, index and all constant buffers
    - render the object

This guideline changes more or less slightly as you advance in progress. For example you could sort the objects by shaders, geometry and so on and set the buffers accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for very complex anserw. From it, I have understood that I should have only one vertex and one index buffer? I guess that because you told to create it before render loop, but my objects can be added during the working of program, not just before first render.

Comment: But even then, the new objects will be probably based on some existing geometry. If not, it is no problem, if you create the vertex buffers on creation of the objects. If your geometry is the same for all objects (besides some transformation), you need only one vertex/index buffer, indeed.

Comment: if the geometry is of the same type, you only need one buffer for each  type of geometry. Then if the data of the geometry (vertex position, normal...) changes in each frame, you can use map/unmap methods.